# when do you close a Subscriber whos emisor is an Observable with a debounce?

Tags: java, rx-java

I am new on java rx and I was wondering if this is possible.

I have an observable with data that keeps coming from a controller.

And it does something like this:

```java
observable.asObservable().debounce(10, SECONDS).subscribe(mySubscriber);

final Subscriber<Long> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<Long>() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("killing the subscriber");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(final Long number) {
            //some stuff
        }
    };
```

Works great, the debounce and the onNext, but when I stop sending events I was waiting the last debounce (with no info) will call the onCompleted() but it doesnt

I need to set a timeout after the last debounce is triggered, taking in consideration that an event can be published after N time.

For example.

If I have a debounce of 10 seconds and a timeout of 20.

I get first event after second 5.

Debounce is triggered and will wait another 10 seconds.

I get second event at second 14.

Debounce is triggered and I will wait until second 24.

Timeout is triggered at second 20 and kills the subscriber.

At second 24 I should get the event at the subscriber but was already killed.

I want to set the timeout AFTER the last emitted taking into consideration the debounce.

Comment: You have to have the `observable` to complete in some way. If it is a subject, call `onCompleted()` and the chain will complete. If it is a generator, stop it by some means such as `timeout` with an `Observable.empty()` fallback.

Comment: but its a "dynamic" observable that is emitting an event from time to time, what I want is that if has not emitted for a N amount of time, my subscriber will close

Comment: I already mentioned that case in my previous comment: use `timeout()`.

Comment: times @akarnokd I am wondering how to use the timeout properly, for example, if I have a debounce of 10 seconds and a timeout of 20, what happen if I get a message on my first 5 seconds, it calls debounce and waits another 10, then I get another at 15 and it will wait another 10 , until reach 25, but my timeout will be already triggered and kill my subscriber, so when I emit the event will not have any subscriber, how can I properly use the timeout then?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if what I am suggesting is the most elegant way, but you can just record last object received and then re-emit it on timeout like so

```
AtomicReference<Long> lastObject = new AtomicReference<>(null);

Observable
    .interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .doOnNext(i -> lastObject.set(i))
    .debounce(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Observable.create(emitter -> {
        if (lastObject.get() != null) emitter.onNext(lastObject.get());
        emitter.onComplete();
    }))
    .subscribe(...);
```

In this example we emit every 100 millis and since debounce is higher no items are emitted. So when `timeout` happens we re-emit last item that we have remembered in `doOnNext` before `debounce`.